# Javascript complex item removal

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am passing an array of objects to a function whose role is to remove some of those objects according to some sort of criterium.

The problem is that the scope isn't being handled the way I would like it to be, and the original array is not being updated.

In that function, the return value is already used and may not be changed. How might I be able to change the array?

Comment: Please provide some code with example of expected input and output

Comment: Please post any existing code you have too :)

Comment: I have re-phased the question as to make it easier to absorb.

Answer (score 0):

A variable pointing to an array is a reference to it. When you pass an array, you're copying this reference. So you should just modify the array parameter and it will modify the original array.

```
var a=[1,2,3];
var c=f(a);
alert(a); // a is now [1,2,3,6]

function f(b) {
    b.push(6);
    return 1;
}
```